# Using Django paginator with nested templates with different number of displays

Tags: pagination, django-templates, django-views

I am working with Django Paginator to set up my list view. In my default list view I've used `"paginate_by=12"` and then I need to show links with drop down to paginate by 20 and all. The list view includes Grid View and List View templates. I am including the templates with grid and list view but I can't control pagination with different numbers. Simply I am using a single view and including multiple templates for that list view...but how to use different paginator size in different tempaltes when I've set it as `paginate_by=20` in my class based list view.
View:

```
class ProductListView(ListView):
    model = Product
    paginate_by = 10
```

I tried using `{% include 'listview30.html' paginate_by=30 %}` but it didn't worked. How to use multiple pagination with a single list view.
Kindly advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-pagination. I've tested it on different pages and it is working fine for me.